# How to enable SPI on Orange PI PC+ in Armbian?

Tags: armbian

I'm trying to get SPI working on my board. 
That's what I came up:

- SPI is not enabled by default in armbian, we need to enable it first
  (enable corresponding DT overlay)
- in linux SPI can only be accessed via /dev/spidev*.* files
- if I don't see any spi devices in my dev folder then SPI is not enabled on my board
- in the latest versions of armbian spi can be enabled in armbain-config (under
  System/Hardware/spi-spidev)
- in previous versions it was needed to decompile `/boot/script.bin` into fex file,  enable SPI there and compile it back

I did clean install of Armbian Bionic (I also did try Stretch earlier), updated it and enabled spi-spidev,  restarted the board but still got no spidev files.

Here is my [`armbianmonitor`  log](http://ix.io/1yZ6).
That's how I check if SPI is enabled:

```
dima@orangepipcplus:~$ cat /boot/armbianEnv.txt
verbosity=1
logo=disabled
console=both
disp_mode=1920x1080p60
overlay_prefix=sun8i-h3
rootdev=UUID=09e9478d-c7f2-4b16-a2d7-66f5313ff813
rootfstype=ext4
overlays=spi-add-cs1 spi-jedec-nor spi-spidev
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
dima@orangepipcplus:~$ ls /dev/*spi*
ls: cannot access '/dev/*spi*': No such file or directory
```

BTW, my goal is to create smart home project with nrf24l01 communication, but I'm stuck on script error that says `could not open /dev/spidev0.0` (not exact paste)

So my question is: **how to enable spi so that `/dev/spidev*.*` files will appear?**

Comment: I would guess you would need to edit a dts compile it to a dtb, then swap it with the one uboot is useing (might need to remake a initial-ram-disk if that is in use, and recompile the kernel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this was really stupid. I just needed to read about [Device Tree overlays](https://docs.armbian.com/Hardware_Allwinner_overlays/) carefully.

I didn't set the required SPI parameter `param_spidev_spi_bus`. Here is my `armbianEnv.txt` now:

```
verbosity=1
logo=disabled
console=both
disp_mode=1920x1080p60
overlay_prefix=sun8i-h3
rootdev=UUID=09e9478d-c7f2-4b16-a2d7-66f5313ff813
rootfstype=ext4
overlays=spi-spidev
param_spidev_spi_bus=0
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
```

Note that **armbain-config** does not set this parameter, so you can't get SPI working using this tool only. So for now it's easier just to edit `armbianEnv.txt` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Orange Pi Lite with [Armbian](https://www.armbian.com/) installed.I have a MCP3208 analog to digital converter retrieving data from some sensors and I did what rattrapper said, but, in my case, the SPI interface didn't work. I finally solved it doing the following:

1. In the command line:
   `sudo armbian-config -> system -> hardware -> enable spi-spidev`
2. Check the SPI parameter `param_spidev_spi_bus = 0` just like rattraper explained in the file /boot/armbianEnv.txt. In overlays must be spi-spidev written.
3. Make sure that the library spidev is installed with the following command:        `sudo pip3 install spidev`
4. Finally, make sure that you are importing the spidev library in your script: `import spidev`

This is what worked for me, so I hope that it works for you too.